# How to plot the following output with plotly?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I would like to use plotly to plot a bar plot of country (x-axis) vs count_of_visited (y-axis). Below is my code. Upon running it the graph is totally wrong.

```
print(categorical.value_counts())

=======================
**Output >>>** 
Japan             16
Spain             8
Italy             10
Name: country, dtype: int64
=======================


# construct a dataframe with columns 'name' and 'country'
df = pd.DataFrame(df_bbb, columns=['name', 'country'])

# construct 2-way frequency table for name & country
df_freq = pd.crosstab(index=df['name'],columns=df['country'],margins=True, margins_name='Total')

print(df_freq)

=======================
**Output >>>** 

country   Japan  Spain  Italy   Total
name
                            
Sam        1       2    1        4
Tim        2       1    2        5
Ash        3       2    3        8
...       ...   ...    ...      ...
...       ...   ...    ...      ...
...       ...   ...    ...      ...
...       ...   ...    ...
Total     ...   ...    ...      34                     

25 rows × 4 columns
=========================


x_axis = df_freq.columns
y_axis = df_freq['Total']


chart1 = [go.Scatter(x=x_axis, y=y_axis, mode='markers')]


layout1 = go.Layout(title='Country vs Visit-count', xaxis={'title':'Country'}, yaxis={'title':'Count of visit'})

fig1 = go.Figure(data=chart1,layout=layout1)

pyo.plot(fig1,filename='chart1.html')
```

My desired output graph:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOitP.png)

Appreciate the help and explanation. Some reference links would be great too!

Comment: Based on your desired graph image and data also, you need bar plot not histogram as you mentioned in question description. correct me if got your question wrong.

Comment: Yes you're right, it's a bar plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your code shows column totals, I think you should set it to column totals and make it a bar graph.

```
x_axis = df_freq.columns[1:4]
y_axis = df_freq.loc['Total',df_freq.columns[1:4]]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x_axis, y=y_axis))
fig.update_layout(title='Country vs Visit-count',
                    xaxis={'title':'Country'},
                    yaxis={'title':'Count of visit'})

fig.show()
```

[image]